# Ruby on rails beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I m new to ruby on rails , was working on this simple application.

I m getting this error:

```
asad@asad:~$ ruby ./Bookmarker/script/generate scaffold Bookmark
/home/asad/Bookmarker/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection': adapter:mysql2 database:bookmarker host:localhost username:root password:*** database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /home/asad/Bookmarker/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
from /home/asad/Bookmarker/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
from ./Bookmarker/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:392:in `initialize_database'
from ./Bookmarker/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:139:in `process'
from ./Bookmarker/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
from ./Bookmarker/script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
from /home/asad/Bookmarker/config/environment.rb:13
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /home/asad/Bookmarker/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from ./Bookmarker/script/generate:3
```

Below is the output from:

```
asad@asad:~$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /var/lib/gems/1.8
   - /home/asad/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

my database.yml is

```
development:
   adapter:mysql2
   database:bookmarker
   host:localhost
   username:root
   password:****
```

Any input on this , would be of great help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either do a `rake db:create` first to initialize your database.

Comment: well , this fixed my problem , add a space before mysql

    development:
       adapter: mysql
       database: bookmarker
       host: localhost
       username: root
       password: **

Comment: The spaces are required because the file format used for database configuration is YAML : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML